# How to normalize style of bs-datepicker nested in table

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-strap

I have a bs-datepicker from angular strap as a td element in a table but the datepicker is inheriting the style of the table (which I would like to keep as is). It is throwing off the look of the datepicker.

[This is a photo of the broken datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OjXb.png)

I have tried adding :not(.datepicker) in the css for all elements but that did not work.

Simplified HTML:

```
<table class="jobs-table" >

            <th>datepicker</th>

            <tr>

              <td>
                <i class="ion-calendar date-icon"></i>
                <input type="text"
                       name="servicedate"
                       class="form-control date-picker-class"
                       ng-model=""
                       bs-datepicker
                        />
                 </td >


            </tr >
</table>
```

The CSS:

```
table {
width: 100%;
}

.jobs-tables tr:first-child {
border-bottom: 5px solid black;
border-top: none;
background-color: #fff;
color: #555;
line-height: 250%;
text-align: left;
}


.jobs-table tr {
border-top: 2px solid black;
line-height: 250%;
}


.tables-table td {
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
max-width: 207px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.tables-table th {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the datepicker is indeed implemented as a table, being more specific in the CSS is the way to go, yes.
As you noticed, replacing `.jobs-table tr` by `.jobs-table :not(.datepicker) tr` didn't work, because the `:not(.datepicker)` can apply to any element inside the outer table (tbody, tr, td) and then the innermost tr does get the style after all.

One solution is to use the `>` combinator, keeping the styles confined to the outer table rather than any table nested inside.

```css
.jobs-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.jobs-tables > tbody > tr:first-child {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 250%;
  text-align: left;
}

.jobs-table > tbody > tr {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  line-height: 250%;
}
```

Not sure what to do with the `tables-table` class though. Is that a class given to the datapicker table, or a different table altogether?